# rancher persistent data lost after reboot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I have installed nfs-provisioner in my rancher cluster. I make persistant volume for my MongoDB. When I restart server or upgrade mongodb container all my data is lost. How to fix this?

My mongodb configuration

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-db
  serviceName: mongo-db
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data #reference the volumeClaimTemplate below
          mountPath: /data/db
  #this is a key difference with statefulsets
  #A unique volume will be attached to each pod
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      #If no storageClassName is provided the default storage class will be used
      #storageClassName: "standard"  
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

Comment: did you use a PVC for mongodb deployment? configuring just PV is not sufficient.

Comment: @leodotcloud i edited my post with mongodb configuration. Is it okay?

Comment: I installed nfs-provisioner, created a SS with replicas=3 using my test image(Don't know how to deal with mongo). Created data in the three replicas, rebooted the node and yet the data was persistent. Could it be possible that your underlying filesystem is not persistent? Where is your machine running? In the cloud? or a VM? And what kind of OS?